# How to Backup from OS X to a Windows Home Server

Tags: backup, windows

I have a Windows Home server in my basement that I've been using as a backup solution when I had a house full of Windows machines. Since making "the switch" to Mac, I haven't been able to find a backup solution I'm happy with.

I tried CrashPlan, but it's way more complicated than I really need. When I was using Windows machines, I just used SyncToy 2.1 and copied files to the server on a predefined schedule. What is out there currently that will let me do something similar on a schedule?

I need a program or script that will let me copy files from specific folders to a Windows server. Keep in mind I'm talking about the old Windows Home Server, not the 2012 version.

I'm not really married to keeping Windows Home Server, but I'd prefer not to have to install a completely new operating system just to backup files.

Comment: Would adding a local USB drive and just using Time Machine be an option as well?

Comment: Not one I would really consider. I don't think Time Machine let's you cherry pick what you want to backup and plus there is no data replication on an external USB drive.

Comment: TM backups the whole disk to an external USB drive though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find that [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://www.bombich.com/) will do what you want. It certainly allows you to create a task to copy a given set of folders to any destination you can mount. It's not expensive ($40 US) and offers a trial version so you can check it out before ponying up the dollars.

I'm assuming you have figured out how to mount your Windows Home Server via SMB.

Answer (score 0):

ChronoSync is an option for syncing Windows and Mac. You can request a trial license key through their website to test it out and see if it works for your situation:
http://www.econtechnologies.com/support/trial-key.php